# How do I make my code remove the sender names found in the messages saved in a txt file and the tags using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, txt

Having this dialogue between a sender and a receiver through Discord, I need to eliminate the tags and the names of the interlocutors, in this case it would help me to eliminate the previous to the colon (:), that way the name of the sender would not matter and I would always delete whoever sent the message.

This is the information what is inside the generic_discord_talk.txt file

```
Company: <@!808947310809317387> Good morning, technical secretary of X-company, will Maria attend you, how can we help you?
Customer: Hi <@!808947310809317385>, I need you to help me with the order I have made
Company: Of course, she tells me that she has placed an order through the store's website and has had a problem. What exactly is Maria about?
Customer: I add the product to the shopping cart and nothing happens <@!808947310809317387>
Company: Does Maria have the website still open? So I can accompany you during the purchase process
Client: <@!808947310809317387> Yes, I have it in front of me
```

```py
import collections
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #to then graph the words that are repeated the most

archivo = open('generic_discord_talk.txt', encoding="utf8")
a = archivo.read()

with open('stopwords-es.txt') as f:
    st = [word for line in f  for word in line.split()]
    print(st)
    

stops = set(st)
stopwords = stops.union(set(['you','for','the'])) #OPTIONAL
#print(stopwords)
```

I have created a regex to detect the tags

```py
regex = re.compile("^(<@!.+>){,1}\s{,}(messegeA|messegeB|messegeC)(<@!.+>){,1}\s{,}$")
regex_tag = re.compile("^<@!.+>")
```

I need that the sentence `print(st)` give me return the words to me but without the emitters and without the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove either parts using an alternation `|` matching either from the start of the string to the first occurrence of a comma, or match <@! till the first closing tag.

```
^[^:\n]+:\s*|\s*<@!\d+>
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^:\n]+:\s*` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `:` or a newline, then match `:` and optional whitspace chars
- `|` Or
- `\s*<@!` Match literally, preceded by optional whitespace chars
- `[^<>]+` Negated character class, match 1+ occurrences of any char except `<` and `>`
- `>` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MF1KlU/1)

If there can be only digits after `<@!`

```
^[^:\n]+:|<@!\d+>
```

For example

```
archivo = open('generic_discord_talk.txt', encoding="utf8")
a = archivo.read()
st = re.sub(r"^[^:\n]+:\s*|\s*<@![^<>]+>", "", a, 0, re.M)
```

If you also want to clear the leading and ending spaces, you can add this line

```
st = re.sub(r"^[^\S\n]*|[^\S\n]*$", "", st, 0, re.M)
```

Comment: Really thanks for the help! PD: Sorry, I deleted the previous comment because I had an unstable connection and it appeared duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
import re


data = """Company: <@!808947310809317387> Good morning, technical secretary of X-company, will Maria attend you, how can we help you?
Customer: Hi <@!808947310809317385>, I need you to help me with the order I have made
Company: Of course, she tells me that she has placed an order through the store's website and has had a problem. What exactly is Maria about?
Customer: I add the product to the shopping cart and nothing happens <@!808947310809317387>
Company: Does Maria have the website still open? So I can accompany you during the purchase process
Client: <@!808947310809317387> Yes, I have it in front of me"""


def run():
    for line in data.split("\n"):
        line = re.sub(r"^\w+: ", "", line)  # remove the customer/company part
        line = re.sub(r"<@!\d+>", "", line)  # remove tags
        print(line)
```

Comment: How to combine all the `line` after the for loop into a new string that stores in a variable?
Because then I need use all the text without the emisors and tags to `text = [word for word in a.lower().split() if word not in stopwords]`

Comment: How to combine all the `lines` after the for loop into a new string that stores in a variable?
Only now the variable `a` is not `a = archivo.read()`, because the variable `a` now would be all the `line` combined in a new string of characters.